# I am failing to install Selenium module via command line

Tags: selenium

I use Ubuntu 16.10. I tried installing Selenium module of python via the command - sudo pip3 install -U selenium. But, I am not able to install it. It is giving an unexpected error. I am sharing the screenshot of the terminal here. Please help!
[Please click here for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY4mf.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu, I'd suggest checking in the package manager as it may already be there. I'm on Mint and it was already there when I loaded python (2.7 also).